# jQuery-ui autocomplete IE6 z-index problem

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, z-index

I am implementing jQuery-ui autocomplete function in my website. In IE6, the autocomplete box appears below other html elements select, input etc. These elements overlap the autocomplete suggestions box. In IE7, 8, it works fine.

I tried changing the z-index of parent div. I changed the z-index of parent div of input, to which I have attached the autocomplete, to 99. Then I set the style for parent div of other elements to 0. But this did not work.

Anybody else had same problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [bgiframe plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bgiframe). It addresses this specific problem.